# Calculating expectation including score function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I can't come up with an efficient solution of the following problem.

---

Let $(X, Y)$ be a 2-dimensional random variable vector which follows the
2-dimensional Gaussian distribution, and its probabilistic density function is, 
\begin{align*}
f(x, y|\ \rho) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}
\exp\left(-\frac{x^2-2\rho xy+y^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right)
\end{align*}
where $-\infty<x, y<\infty;\ |\rho|<1$.

Find the following conditional expectation, 
\begin{align*}
E\left[Y^2\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}\log{f(X, Y|\ \rho)\ \Big|\ X= x}\right]
\end{align*}

---

My solution is straightforward. I calculated the inside of the big parentheses, used the additive formula of expectation, and then find 2, 3, and 4 dimensional probability moment of $Y$.

The problem is that my solution is time-consuming, and induces mistakes in calculation.
The good properties of the score function may be useful, in my opinion, but
I couldn't make use of them in the end.

Please tell me more efficient way of solving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that $f(x,y;\rho) = f(y|x ; \rho) f(x;\rho)$, where
\begin{equation}
f(y|x;\rho) = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}} e^{-(y-\rho x )^2/2(1-\rho^2)}, 
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
f(x; \rho)=f(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} e^{-x^2/2} .
\end{equation}

Note that $f(x)$ does not depend on $\rho$, therefore
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \log f(x,y;\rho)}{\partial \rho} &=\frac{1}{f(x,y;\rho)}\frac{\partial f(x,y;\rho)}{\partial \rho}\\
&= \frac{f(x)}{f(x,y;\rho)} \frac{\partial f(y|x;\rho)}{\partial \rho}\\
&= \frac{1}{f(y|x;\rho)} \frac{\partial f(y|x;\rho)}{\partial \rho}
\end{align}

Now,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left(Y^2 \frac{\partial \log f(x,y;\rho)}{\partial \rho} |X=x\right)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y|x;\rho) y^2 \frac{\partial \log f(x,y;\rho)}{\partial \rho} dy \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y|x;\rho) y^2 \frac{1}{f(y|x;\rho)} \frac{\partial f(y|x;\rho)}{\partial \rho} dy \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty  y^2  \frac{\partial f(y|x;\rho)}{\partial \rho} dy \\
&=\frac{\partial  }{\partial \rho}\int_{-\infty}^\infty  y^2 f(y|x;\rho)   dy \\
&=\frac{\partial  }{\partial \rho} \mathbb{E}\left(Y^2|X=x\right),
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your answer was very helpful to my comprehension!